# How to print current index or for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

The below PHP code returns 12345678910...... at a stretch.

```
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
      sleep(1);
      echo $i;
}
```

How can I get it to print only the current loop number instead of printing all numbers together?

Comment: What's the expected output? Echoing data cannot be reversed simply

Comment: Mayen add a newline?

Comment: Are you wondering why you get all the numbers at the same time after 1000 seconds instead of a new one each second because of `sleep(1)`?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, this question is perfectly clear

Comment: Well, it's clear, as long as it's php **CLI**

Comment: I also think that the question should be re-opened. This is the 1st time I vote to reopen a closed post

Comment: @RiggsFolly, My answer will not be echoing a new line.

Comment: @KenLee Its almost worth reopening just to see what you think the answer to this is :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh no buddy, I think Ken has the same idea than me and it's way cleaner than a simple `PHP_EOL`

Comment: @Cid And nothing like my comment?

Comment: I wouldn't vote to reopen if the answer would be a simple new line

Comment: @Karthik When you have time, I think some feedback would be helpful to clear up some of the assumptions the answerers are making about exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done in **php cli** using the backspace character `"\x08"`

```
<?php
$length = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
    // delete as much character as the length of the previous number
    echo str_repeat("\x08", $length);

    sleep(1);
    echo $i;

    // get the length of the number, so you know how much you have to delete
    $length = strlen((string)$i);
}
```

Comment: For a php cli, your answer is perfect (I upvoted it)

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggested answer (applicable to browser)

a) I believe the OP wants to have the output generated to the browser interface

b) To generate the output of the count during the 1-second sleep, we need to flush the output before each sleep

c) In a browser interface, it is not possible to generate a backspace, so let's do a javascript trick to update the div

```
<div id=output1></div>
<?php

$index=0;

while($index < 1000) { 

    ob_start();
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML=" . $index . "</script>";

    ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
    flush();    
    sleep(1);
    $index++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe better if you added a bit of an explanation about what you are doing

Comment: OK, will do it now

Comment: _(not just applicable to CLI)_ In fact not applicable at all to the CLI :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you are right, I amended my words

Comment: This is clever!